# Navigation between InAppBrowser to Ionic Page

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser, custom-url

I have an InAppBrowser in my Ionic App and I have inserted an anchor Tag with executeScript.When I click on that  I want to push a new Ionic Page called as Settings Page.How to do this.Please help

```
<a href="appname://settings"></a>
```

But am getting an error called

> The webpage could not be loaded because net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Update:

I have added Ionic Deep Links too.

```
 this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.navChild, {
    '/login': LoginPage,
    '/main':MainPage

  }).subscribe((match) => {
    console.log('Successfully routed', match);
  }, (nomatch) => {
    console.log('Unmatched Route', nomatch);
  });
```

> ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=example.com --variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/
>   Where URL_SCHEME is my appname
>   and DEEPLINK_HOST -web page from where am opening the deep link

Answer (score 0):

Use [DeepLinks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/) to register an urlscheme and route the custom urls in your app.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp 
  --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=example.com 
  --variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/deeplinks
```

- URL_SCHEME - the custom URL scheme you'd like to use for your app.
  This lets your app respond to links like myapp://blah
- DEEPLINK_SCHEME - the scheme to use for universal/app links. Defaults to 'https' in 1.0.13. 99% of the time you'll use https here as iOS and Android require SSL for app links domains.
- DEEPLINK_HOST - the host that will
  respond to deeplinks. For example, if we want
  example.com/product/cool-beans to open in our app, we'd use
  example.com here.
- ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX - (optional): specify which
  path prefix our Android app should open from more info

Comment: I have added Deep links...DEEPLINK_HOST is my webpage domain right?

Comment: U have pasted the Ionic Deeplinks....I have  done the same ....See my Updated question.It's not working

Answer (score 0):

const browser = this.iab.create("https://ionic.io");

```
browser.on('loaderror').subscribe(event => 
{
  if (event.message === 'net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME') {
    browser.close();
    this.iab.create(event.url, '_system');

    // Do whathever you want with your url
    alert("Alert: "+event.url);
  }
});
```